# How can I post or display the file content of a text file inside a modal popup?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem on showing the content of the text file selected by the user in my modal popup.

```
        <input type="file" name="file">

        <div id="myModal3" class="modal2">
            <div id="modal-body2">
                <div class="modal-content2">
                    <hr />
                    <div id="dvView" class="modal-header">
                        <b><font face="Arial" color="black" size = "2">Please notice that during upgrade, page will normally load for 5 minutes or more,</font><br></b>
                        <b><font face="Arial" color="black" size = "2">depending on the quantity of device to upgrade.</font><br></b>
                        <b><font face="Arial" color="black" size = "2">The page usually loads for 5 minutes per device. Kindly wait until results are posted.</font></b>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                        <label for="chkContent2">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkContent2" onclick="ShowHideDiv1(this)" />
                        <b><font face="Arial" color="red" size = "2">View file content?</font></b>

                    </label>
                    <hr />
                <div id="dvContent2" style="display: none">
                        <div class="modal-content3">
                            <?php
                                $filename = $_POST['file']
                                $fullPath = "E:\Data\\".$filename;
                                if (file_exists($fullPath))  {
                                    if ($file = fopen($fullPath, "r")) {
                                        while(!feof($file)) 
                                        {
                                            $line = fgets($file);
                                            list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e ) = array_pad(explode(',', $line,5),5,null);
                                            echo $a, "<br>", $b, "<br>", $c, "<br>", $d . "<br>". $e . "<br><br>";
                                        }
                                        fclose($file);
                                        } 
                                        }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function ShowHideDiv1(chkContent2) {
                            var dvContent2 = document.getElementById("dvContent2");
                            dvContent2.style.display = chkContent2.checked ? "block" : "none";
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the output when I run this code.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: if you remove the `style="display: none"` from `dvContent2` will the content of the file be displayed ?

Comment: what was in `$_POST['file']`? Does the file exist in that location on disk? Does the account that PHP runs under have permission to access it? Does the file contain any content?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui that appears to be controlled by the script. When the checkbox is checked, the div should be displayed. Seems more likely there's a problem with the PHP which gets the file contents.

Comment: You are missing an `;` after `$filename = $_POST['file']`

Comment: good point, it's surprising you don't have a syntax error reported. Have you got all PHP error reporting suppressed?